# Display content of multiple views

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, jqplot

I have a function rendering a chart:

```
function testSave(){
    $this->_renderChart(156);
}
```

this I am using for testing. The testSave() function's view displays the content of `_renderChart(156)` call. But when I do

```
function testSave(){
    $this->_renderChart(156);
    $this->_renderChart(153);
}
```

then it just displays the content of  `$this->_renderChart(153)` call but it doesn't display the content of `$this->_renderChart(156)`.

The `_renderChart($chart_id)` function explained:

```
function _renderChart($chart_id = null){
    if($chart_id == null)
        return false;
    //some magic...
    $this->layout = 'dummyfolder\dummy_layout_name';
}
```

Inside the _renderChart's function's view I have a javascript code that is by ajax saving an image of the chart as `.png` on the server. But it the case when invoking twice `$this->renderChart()` only the last occurence of it is rendered and only one image is saved instead of two.

Comment: The error is probably within "some magic..." which would be helpful to include.

Comment: Why donot you put the different charts in different divs when response is returned using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe it's because you are invoking function for 'this' consecutively. Then it means that $this is always the last invoke. How about initializing the invokes into variables and then returning the variables. Something like this:

```
$var1 = $this->_renderChart(156);
$var2 = $this->_renderChart(153);

return array($var1, $var2);
```

Edit:

```
$array = array("156", "153");
$this->_renderChart($array);
```

and then something like this:

```
function _renderChart($chart_id = null){
    if($chart_id == null)
        return false;
     foreach($chart_id as $key => $value) {
        //some magic...
     }
     $this->layout = 'dummyfolder\dummy_layout_name';
}
```

Comment: Why are you running renderChart function in another function?

Comment: It could be usefull also to see what is the 'magic' part of your code?

Comment: The 'magic' part is setting up the data to later properly display each chart. My goal is to render and save many images in a loop.

Comment: And where do you call testSave function?

Comment: I just open localhost with the url ending with the testSave, that is localhost/myapp/mycontroller/testSave

Comment: Im not familiar with cakePhp framework, but I assume, according to your description, that renderChart prints a view with info specific to parameter you pass to it. So that would mean, that only this parameter is rendered and thus the last invoke that is. My only hint for you now is, to change the function or make a new similar, in which multiple parameters can be passed, and it prints all info according them: chart_id could then be, for example, array of ids.